# com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/xx.xxx.x.xxx:9042] Cannot connect

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I have 2 node in Cassandra cluster with IP:Port aa.aaa.a.aaa:9043(node) and xx.xxx.x.xxx:9043. When i trying to connect using following config **PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
        poolingOptions.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 2)
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 4)
        .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2)
        .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 4)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 200)
        .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 200);

```
    cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPointsWithPorts(socketAddressList)
            .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
            .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy())).build();
    Session session = cluster.connect(cassandraDB);**
```

I am getting following exception **16/01/14 09:52:45 INFO core.NettyUtil: Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
16/01/14 09:52:46 WARN core.Cluster: ***You listed /xx.xxx.x.xxx:9043 in your contact points, but it could not be reached at startup***
16/01/14 09:52:47 INFO policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy: Using data-center name 'name' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)ent.Futures$CombinedFuture setExceptionAndMaybeLog
SEVERE: input future failed.
***com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/xx.xxx.x.xxx:9042] Cannot connect
  at*** com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:156)
  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:139)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:268)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:284)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
***Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /xx.xxx.x.xxx:9042***
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)
  ... 6 more

***16/01/14 09:52:47 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /xx.xxx.x.xxx:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/xx.xxx.x.xxx:9042] Cannot connect
  at*** com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:156)
  at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:139)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:268)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:284)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: **/xx.xxx.x.xxx:9042***
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
  at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:281)**

My Question are:

1. why it is trying to connect on port 9042, while no where i am using this port in code as well as in config file ?

cassandra version: Cassandra 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why it is trying to connect on port 9042, while no where i am using this port in code as well as in config file ?

**9042** is the default port for the CQL binary protocol.

Can you show us the content of the variable *socketAddressList* that you passed to the cluster builder ?

Is there any reason you're using port **9043** instead of the default **9042** port ?

Comment: private static List<InetSocketAddress> socketAddressList = new ArrayList<InetSocketAddress>();socketAddressList.add(new InetSocketAddress(cassandraHosts.get("HOST_1"), cassandraPort));
   socketAddressList.add(new InetSocketAddress(cassandraHosts.get("HOST_2"), cassandraPort)); **HOST_1=xx.xxx.x.xxx, HOST_2=aa.aaa.a.aa, cassandraPort=9043.** No ther is no specific reason.

Comment: Ok, it does not work this way. To set the port to **9043** you need to call method .withPort(9043). The address provided in the list of contact points is ignored by the Cluster builder, it uses the default port, which is 9042. See : https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.java#L685-L692